# what type of nettle is this? or thistle?

Tags: identification, weeds

Northwestern Ohio. These nettles (or maybe thistles?) are growing all over wherever there's partial shade. They grow in bug clumps of individual stalks, the leaves typically pointed a bit upward, long and thin and saw-toothed. Found some that were starting to flower, figured it'd help ID.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not a nettle.

Nettles do not have sharp spines; they inflict pain with formic acid, rather than physical sharpness!